# Why aren't numerical methods sufficient to show existence and uniqueness?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose somebody is modeling a solution (or set of solutions) to a particular partial differential equation (Navier-Stokes maybe) via some software that makes use of some numerical method(s) to solve the partial differential equation. That software will 'converge' to a particular solution to the differential equation.

Shouldn't that be pretty much sufficient to show existence and uniqueness to that differential equation, given that the partial differential equation itself didn't involve any bad operations (dividing by zero maybe)?

I'm sure the answer is no, so what I'm really asking for is why not?

Comment: because computers do not have infinite precision and chaos exists.

Comment: Consider the ordinary differential equation $x'=x^2$ with $x(0)=1$. Using any explicit integration scheme, you can obtain a numerical solution extending arbitrarily far forward in time. But the analytical solution is $x(t)=1/(1-t)$, and does not exist for $t>1$.

Comment: But $1/(1-t)$ does exist for $t>1$, just not $t=1$...

Comment: I have the same equation.  Is it because of the specified boundary conditions and constraints on the system? Can anyone help?